# How to obtain a current page size of the memory MS Windows 7 in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management

How to obtain a current page size of the memory MS Windows 7 in C#?

In some cases we need it to allocate memory in best way.

Thank you!

UPDATES: Here is a sample code... I have some doubts on the line `byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];`

```
// Assign values to these objects here so that they can
// be referenced in the finally block
Stream remoteStream = null;
Stream localStream = null;
WebResponse response = null;

try
{
    response = request.EndGetResponse(result);

    if (response != null)
    {
        // Once the WebResponse object has been retrieved, get the stream object associated with the response's data
        remoteStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        // Create the local file
        string pathToSaveFile = Path.Combine(FileManager.GetFolderContent(), TaskResult.ContentItem.FileName);
        localStream = File.Create(pathToSaveFile);

        // Allocate a 1k buffer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];      
        int bytesRead;

        // Simple do/while loop to read from stream until no bytes are returned
        do
        {
            // Read data (up to 1k) from the stream
            bytesRead = remoteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Comment: Are you **really** sure that knowing the page size allows you to make a better choice on how to allocate your memory? If so, are you sure that C# is the best technology to develop your solution? Would you mind posting an example where knowing the page size would benefit you in your allocation of memory?

Comment: Please see my sample code. As you can see here  byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];    4096 is hardcoded. I need to use the correct value here for example  in cases of MS Windows 7 x86 and x64

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using C# 4.0 there is the property Environment.SystemPageSize that internally uses GetSystemInfo. I never seen it before since it is new.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.systempagesize.aspx

In C you can write something like this.

```
#include <windows.h>
int main(void) {
    SYSTEM_INFO si;
    GetSystemInfo(&si);

    printf("The page size for this system is %u bytes.\n", si.dwPageSize);

    return 0;
}
```

Then, you can use P/INVOKE to call GetSystemInfo.
Take a look at http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getsysteminfo

I must also add that allocating an array of page-size bytes is not the best choice.

First of all, C# memory can be moved, C# uses a compacting generational garbage collector.
There is not any kind of information on where data will be allocated.

Second, arrays in C# can be formed by non-contiguous area of memory! Arrays are stored contiguously in virtual memory but contiguous virtual memory is not contiguous physical memory.

Third, array data structure in C# occupies some bytes more than the content itself (it stores array size and other informations). If you allocate page size amount of bytes, using the array will switch page almost always!

I would think that this optimization can be an non-optimization.

Usually C# arrays performs very well without the need to split memory using page size.

If you really need precise allocation of data you need to use pinned arrays or Marshal allocation, but this will slow down the garbage collector.

I would say it is better to just use your arrays without thinking too much about the page size.

Answer (score 2):

Use pinvoke to call [GetSystemInfo()](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetSystemInfo.html) and use the dwPageSize value.  Although you probably really want dwAllocationGranularity, which is the smallest block [VirtualAlloc()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will allocate instead.

Comment: Thanks guys! It's exactly what I asked for! http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getsysteminfo  so now I can do this...                     WinApi.SYSTEM_INFO sysinfo = new WinApi.SYSTEM_INFO();
                    WinApi.GetSystemInfo(ref sysinfo);

                    // Allocate a buffer 
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[int.Parse(sysinfo.dwPageSize.ToString())];